# Present in input array

Tags: java, aggregation-framework

We have a stocks collection:

```
stocks:

{"_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),"scrip" : "xxxxx2" }
{"_id" : ObjectId("xxy"),"scrip" : "xxxxx3" }
{"_id" : ObjectId("xyy"),"scrip" : "..." }
```

Given an input array of scrips `[xxxxx7,xxxxx2,xxxxx3,xxxxx8]`,we need to return an array of the scrips not present in the stocks collection.
So the expected output is :

```
[xxxxx7,xxxxx8]
```

Is there a way to achieve this using Filter.expr and $setIsSubset(or any other alternative).
Not able to get an example of the same.
Help is appreciated

Comment: You could try `db.stocks.find({ '$expr': { '$not': { '$in: [ "$scripid" , inputArray ] } } }).toArray().map(doc => doc.scripid)`?

Comment: Thanks.But what is the equivalent using java driver aggregate.We are using driver 3.5+

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data in collection :

**stocks:**

```
{"scripid" : "xxxxx2" }
{"scripid" : "xxxxx3" }
{"scripid" : "xxxxx4" }
```

So if you need to get the list of elements from **Input Array** which are not in  **scripid** of stocks collection, but not the list of elements from stocks collection which are not in input array, then use this:

```
db.stocks.aggregate([  {
             $group :{_id : null, scripids: {$push : '$scripid'}}
           },{ "$project": { _id:0 , "inputArrayNINscripts": { "$setDifference": [ ['xxxxx7','xxxxx2','xxxxx3','xxxxx8'] , "$scripids" ] } } } ])
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "inputArrayNINscripts" : [ 
        "xxxxx7", 
        "xxxxx8"
    ]
}
```

Else if you need list of elements(scripid's) from stocks **scripid** which aren't in passed `[xxxxx7,xxxxx2,xxxxx3,xxxxx8]` then, as suggested by @Caconde try this :

```
db.stocks.find({
    "scripid": {"$nin": ["xxxxx7","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx8"]} 
}).toArray().map(scriptsNINArray => scriptsNINArray.scripid)
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
[
    "xxxxx4"
]
```

**Add-ons:**

As requested for java code, Please check these references:

[mongoDB-java-driver Aggregation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/) ,  [SO link to java aggregation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351139/mongodb-aggregation-command-to-java-code)

Comment: Could not find the setDifference function for java driver though

Comment: @IUnknown : not sure about java driver, but does the query work in DB ? Please put on a tag for JAVA or raise a new question, meanwhile just found something here in SO, Please check this for java : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351139/mongodb-aggregation-command-to-java-code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected result with MongoDB's **Not In** operator [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) and mapping the result to an array:

```
db.stocks.find({
    "scripid": {"$nin": ["xxxxx7","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx8"]} 
}).toArray().map(stock => stock.scripid)
```